# Insertar una Variable con un Array a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Quiero agregar una Variable que contiene un array, los datos del array son obtenido mediante una serie de inputs creado mediante ajax y un for, al momento de ingresar la variable a mysql solo me captura el ultimo dato ingresado, quisiera saber cual es el error o quizás falta agregar algún tipo de parametro.

prueba.php

```
if(isset($_POST['add_medidor'])){
$req_fields = array('nguia','fase','fecharegistro','serie');

    if(empty($errors)){
      $nguia      = $db->escape($_POST['nguia']);
      $fase     = $db->escape($_POST['fase']);
      $fechareg      = $db->escape($_POST['fecharegistro']);
      $resultado = $_POST['serie'];
      foreach ($resultado as $valor){
       echo $valor;
      $serie=$valor;

      $sql  = "INSERT INTO medidores (";
      $sql .= " nguia,fase,fecharegistro,serie";
      $sql .= ") VALUES (";
      $sql .= "'{$nguia}','{$fase}','{$fechareg}','{$serie}'";
      $sql .= ")";}             
      } 
     }

     <form method="post" action="add_medidor.php">       
     <table class="table table-bordered">
       <thead> 
      <tr>
          <th>N° de Guia</th>
          <th>Fase</th>
          <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="nguia" placeholder="N° de Guia"></td>
          <td><select class="form-control" name="fase">    
          <option value="Monofasico">Monofásico</option>    
          <option value="Trifasico">Trifásico</option>      
          </select></td>
          <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="datepicker form-control" name="fecharegistro" placeholder="Fecha de Registro"></td>
      </tr>

       </thead>
         <tbody  id="product_info"> </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class='link' onClick="realizaProceso($('#cantidad').val());return false;">
    <strong>
      <span>Ingrese la Cantidad de Medidores a Ingresar</span>
   </strong>
   <br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Cantidad de Medidores" autocomplete="off" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="form-control" style="width : 300px; heigth : 300px"/></div></th>
<br>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function realizaProceso(valor1){
    var parametros = {
            "valor1" : valor1
    };
    $.ajax({

            data:  parametros,
            url:   'proceso.php',
            type:  'post',

            beforeSend: function () { 
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },

            success:  function (response) {
                    $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
    });
    } </script>

    <div class='link' id="resultado"> Ingrese Medidores: </div>
    <br>
    <button onClick="return confirm('Estas seguro de Agregar?');" type="submit" 
    name="add_medidor" 
    class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Medidores</button>
   </form>
```

proceso.php

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST["valor1"]))
    {
   $resultado = $_POST['valor1'];
   for($i=1;$i<=$resultado;$i++){
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><strong>Serie <?php echo $i; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
   <td><input placeholder="Serie" autocomplete="off" name="serie[]" id="serie" type="text" 
   size="30" maxlength="30" class="form-control"></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } }?>
```

Todo parte de prueba.php, mediante el Ajax que es proceso.php se crean los inputs en el mismo prueba.php y activar el boton del form agrega solo el ultimo de los digitos digitados en los inputs creados.

ejemplo:
si en cantidad de inputs se digita 3, se crean 3 inputs en los cuales se digitan los valores, 32, 44 y 55 y al momento de activar el boton solo digita en la base de datos una fila con el valor 55

Comment: ¿donde está lo que haces después con $sql?  no se si te das cuenta que lo estás sobreescribiendo en cada ciclo y cuando termina solo tienes la ultima consulta pues ya has sobreescrito las otras. La solución es o bien vas concatenandolas o bien las vas ejecutando en cada ciclo, pero no veo donde la ejecutas.

Comment: buenas tardes, no entiendo bien la pregunta de q se hace con $sql, cambie el codigo y me sigue agregando el ultimo valor del ultimo input, sera que no esta reconociendolo un array? el codigo lo cambie asi, de estar algo mal podrias guiarme un poco mediante una explicacion con codigo?

         `$sql  = "INSERT INTO medidores (serie) VALUES ('{$series}')";`

me sigue agregando el ultimo valor de los inputs

Comment: No veo donde ejecutas la cadena del $sql, tan solo veo que la creas pero no veo un query, prepare y/o execute de la misma... ¿donde lo haces?

Comment: con una funcion query

`public function query($sql)
   { if (trim($sql != "")) {
          $this->query_id = $this->con->query($sql);
      }`

Comment: Vale, pero si te das cuenta esa función solo la ejecutas una vez, en cambio el $sql lo tienes dentro de un bucle, por lo tanto deberias ejecutarla cada vez después de que defines el $sql en cada ciclo, porque sino $sql solo contendrá lo que tenga el último ciclo cuando ejecutas el query fuera del ciclo (que es el problema que dices que tienes)

Comment: @masterguru lo tenia todo el tiempo en la cara y no me di cuenta, muchas gracias esa fue la solución!!!

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos errores lógicos, cada vez que llamas al post add_medidor reinicias la variable $sql o por lo menos eso dice el código que dejaste. También si $sql es la variable del array y agregas varias consultas sql debes agregar un punto y coma para terminar la consulta. Ej: insert xxx; insert xxx; insert xxx;